# Node Promise Seems To Be Trickling Back Data, Some Looks Like A Buffer?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, httprequest, chunks

I'm making an async https request.  I'm getting data back but it seems like it's trickling in rather than coming back as a single response from the server.  Some of it even seems like it's coming back as some kind of buffer.  Has anyone seen anything like this?

I'm trying to understand if the why the async 'on data' is coming in in pieces. The server is set up to deliver a single response back.

```
//Start JS File


var port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    https = require('https'),
    html = fs.readFileSync('index.html');

const server = http.createServer();

server.on('request', async (req, res) => {
    let myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const data = JSON.stringify({
            someData:'someData'
        });

        const options = {
            hostname: 'gs.aURL.com',
            port: 443,
            path: '/openrtb2/auction',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
                'Content-Length': data.length,
                Accept: '*/*',
                pragma: 'no-cache',
                'User-Agent':
                    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36',
                Cookie:
                    'uids=eyJ0ZW1wVUlEcyI6eyIzM2Fjcm9zcyI6eyJ1aWQiOiIyMTAyNDE4OTIxOTc2MTciLCJleHBpcmVzIjoiMjAyMC0wMy0yN1QyMTo1MToyOC42MDkxNjEyODZaIn0sImFkbnhzIjp7InVpZCI6IjY3ODE0NTEzMjgzOTg1NTE3MDkiLCJleHBpcmVzIjoiMjAyMC0wMy0yN1QyMTo1MTozMy41Mjg0OTgzMjhaIn0sInB1bHNlcG9pbnQiOnsidWlkIjoiOE1WYlRlMTRQSFhVIiwiZXhwaXJlcyI6IjIwMjAtMDMtMjdUMjE6NTE6MzMuMTI5NDI2NjIyWiJ9fSwiYmRheSI6IjIwMjAtMDMtMTNUMjE6NTE6MjguNjA5MTU1MThaIn0=',
                origin: 'https://lab.fizz.org'
            }
        };

        const adRequest = https.request(options, (adResponse) => {
            //console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);

            adResponse.on('data', (d) => {
                console.log(typeof d);
                res.write(d);
                resolve(d);
            });
        });

        adRequest.on('error', (error) => {
            reject(error);
        });

        adRequest.write(data);
        adRequest.end();
    })
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
            res.write(result);

            req.end();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            //res.write(error);
            //req.end();
        });
});

// Listen on port 3000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(port);

// Put a friendly message on the terminal
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:' + port + '/');

//END JS File



Output to terminal (from console.log(typeof d)):
====================================================================


object
<Buffer 7b 22 69 64 22 3a 22 66 39 34 35 64 34 64 65 2d 33 36 61 37 2d 34 38 65 37 2d 38 64 65 64 2d 35 62 63 63 61 66 32 35 39 37 66 36 22 2c 22 73 65 61 74 ... >
object
object
object
object
object
object
object
object
object
object
object
object
object
object
object
object
object
object
object
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` events on streams (that are not in object mode) contain an arbitrary amount of data.  You may get all your data from the stream in one `data` event or it may come in a whole bunch of `data` events.  This is somewhat analagous to reading a TCP stream (since the underlying http protocol is just using a TCP stream) where data arrives in arbitrary chunks.

How many chunks it arrives in has to do with a whole bunch of factors, none of which you control including:

- How the sender sends the data
- How fast the sender's network connection is
- How fast the internet link between you and the sender is
- How fast your computer can get data off the network
- What might happen to the data as it traverses the internet to get to you

And so on...

So, if you really just want ALL the data, then you need to collect all the data in the `data` events, combine it together and then in the `end` event you will know that you now have ALL the data.

If you want meaningful pieces of data along the way, then you have to parse the data as it comes in so that you can find the boundaries of some meaningful amount of data (such as lines or some other object boundary).  And, you have to be prepared that you may receive a partial piece of data, have to buffer that partial data until the rest of it comes in on the next data event.  This is how you do incremental parsing of incoming streams.

That `data` event is coming from the incoming stream.  Depending upon how the stream is configured, the `data` event will either offer a Buffer object (which it looks like yours is) or a String.

Comment: @nickstark - Does this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and also earn yourself some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.